# remote simple_form_for with re-defined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Cheers!

```
= simple_form_for :search_input, :url => 'tracks/result', :method => :get do |f|
```

How to make this form `:remote => true` correctly?

Comment: It is ok, but for the json responses you will need to add a `format: :json` for your url, like: `:url: {resource_url(:format => :json)) }` (for some browsers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
= simple_form_for(:search_input, :url => 'tracks/result', :method => :get, :remote => true) do |f|
```

Comment: Oh, thank you for reaction, but I just forgot to add format.html and format.js, so newbie, sorry.